# Local Ubuntu Machine Refuses to import Pandas due to unfound Module 'pd.core.dtypes.common'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop refuses to `import pandas`.  I have tried re installing and updating pandas countless times.  I use a list to load all my libraries.  To make sure there was not a conflict in libraries or compatibility issue I reloaded every element on my script on this local machine AND simultaineously on an Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64 cloud server.  When I tried to import pandas on the cloud server it worked no problem.  When I tried to import pandas on my local machine I continued to get this error.

Then I tried installing pandas using pip instead of conda and it still refused to import however the error changed.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions or need any additional information.

```
import pandas as pd 

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.dtypes.common'

=====================================================================
```

After `pip install`:

```
import pandas as pd

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) 
ImportError: cannot import name 're_type'
```

Comment: I tried to cut and paste the entire error script but the webpage rejected to formatting...

Comment: I opened an older jupyter notebook created on this local machine.  When I executed the cell to import pandas I got an error that read  ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'

Comment: Would be helpful to know the exact version of python and pandas

Comment: Hi Anna, apparently I have two versions of python installed 2.7.12 AND 3.6.4  .   I have been installing pandas=0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using different versions of python. Perhaps both Python 2 and Python 3

Check the version of Python and install it in the same.

To install within python 2 use `pip` command

To install within python 3 use `pip3` command

Check python version by

`python --version`

```
Python 3.6.5
```

OR

```
>>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Prateek.  When I check python --version in root output = Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.  This is what I installed.  However, I have been told that python 2.x is factory installed in Ubuntu OS.  When I check in the normal user output = Python 2.7.12.  This leads me to believe that YES both of these versions are present in the OS.  I don't think I need 2.7.12.  Can I / Should I delete this version somehow to avoid these errors?  I am not sure what you mean by "install it in the same."

Comment: I also wanted to mention that I usually install pandas with the command.  
   conda install pandas=0.19   Can a conda install be a factor?

Comment: I tried pip3 install pandas.  The output said "requirement already satisfied," and the error continues to occur.

Comment: Dont use pip within anaconda. thats the issue. To install a package use `conda install` command or use anaconda navigator. Make sure to enable conda environement before working on that .

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Prateek.  I dont think that a pip / conda conflict is the issue because I have tried installing each separately and when I got the error initially I was using conda script that I am confident was free from package manager and library conflicts.  I think your first suggestion that there are conflicts with two versions of python that exist on the OS.  I just wish I knew the best way to resolve.

Comment: @Ludlow_Luddite I checked GitHub of pandas python version support was started from pandas version `0.19.2 Final` so install that or above version. Please note latest version is `0.23`